# How to measure time of asynchronous reading data from database

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I would like to read asynchronous data from database and measure time of this reading. I am using `CompletableFuture.runAsync`method.

In my application I have lots of class like:

```java
public class ReadDataFromDB implements IInitialization {

    @Override
    public void init() throws ReadingException {
        //delegate to other class which will read data from db      
    }
}
```

Initialization is functional interface with one method `public void init() throws ReadingException`

I collect all of these classes to list:

```java
List<IInitialization> input = Arrays.asList(new ReadDataFromDB(), ...);
```

and run it asynchronous:

```java
long l = input.stream().map(i -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        i.init();
    } catch (ReadingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, threadPool)).count();
```

Worker pool I defined as:

```java
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, r -> {

    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(null);
    return thread;
});
```

All of this I have in one method `private void readDataAsync() throws ReadingException`

I try to measure time by:

```java
long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
readDataAsync();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("readDataAsync: " + (end - begin) / 1000.0);
```

This way does not work, because console show `readDataAsync: 0.043`, server started, but my client sees the data after a few seconds (faster than synchronous).

Any ideas how can I right measure this time of reading asynchronous data from DB ?